# Did the second Defiant (the renamed Sao Paulo) have a cloak?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

The original Defiant-class Defiant was equipped with a cloaking device, initially operated by [a Romulan advisor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/143483/20774), and then just by members of the regular Starfleet crew.

After its destruction, a second ship (the [USS Sao Paulo](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Sao_Paulo)) from the same class was assigned to DS9 and renamed the USS Defiant, presumably to help prevent confusion among infrequent viewers.

---

**Did the second Defiant have a cloaking device?**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both the Memory-Alpha and the Memory-Beta page for the USS Sao Paulo say that the ship had a new cloaking device.

[Memory-Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/USS_Sao_Paulo#Apocrypha):

> In Books One and Two of the duology Star Trek: Deep Space Nine - Avatar, the first books in a series set after "What You Leave Behind", the Defiant was described as having been fitted with a new Romulan cloaking device, the Romulan Senate having recognized the strategic importance of the Defiant as the first line of defense against any future Dominion attack through the wormhole.

[Memory-Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NX-74205)_(II)#History):

> Following the war, the Romulan Senate moved to allow the Defiant to
>   keep the borrowed Romulan cloaking device it utilized. Such a move
>   recognized the importance of the vessel, and Deep Space 9, as the
>   first line of defense against further Dominion attacks. (DS9 novel:
>   Avatar, Book One)

Comment: You may have my +1 for finding evidence from the Expanded universe books. Is there any evidence that's from the actual shows?

Comment: No, both quotes state that the Sao Paulo only got its cloaking device after the end of the show.